# How to increase memcache slab size above 1MB with dalli and Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, dalli

I'm using Ruby on Rails and dalli gem to do caching with memcache.

The default value (value as in key-value store, aka slab) max size is 1MB.

I would like to increase this to 2MB.

[The documentation of dalli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656999/how-to-cache-files-over-1mb-with-rack-cache-on-heroku) says:

`value_max_bytes: The maximum size of a value in memcached. Defaults to 1MB, this can be increased with memcached's -I parameter. You must also configure Dalli to allow the larger size here.`

With the `-I` option of `memcached`, how do I specify 2MB?  Is it -I2 or -I2000?  (the documentation isn't clear on this)

For the dalli gem, I have, in `environments/development.rb`

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store
```

I don't have explicit mention of Dalli::Client.new
So how can I set the `value_max_bytes`?

I've looked at [the related question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17656999/how-to-cache-files-over-1mb-with-rack-cache-on-heroku), it seems that I need to install the rack-cache gem.  Is this necessary?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Start the `memcached` with the command:

```
memcached -p 11211 -I2m
```

In Rails environment file, eg config/environments/production.rb, use the following syntax:

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store, { value_max_bytes: 2000000 }
```